# Out of memory error on access

Tags: out-of-memory, ms-access-2010

I have an out of memory error on access. My DB is approx 20mb and holds approx 100,000 lines in different tables.

It started this afternoon, whenever i go in the VBA editor, i can't edit anything, because it will delete the text i just typed, and popup "Out of memory".

If i try to use a OnUpdate event on a DropDown list, it will say the same error, and will do nothing.  I can't even setup a break point on my code, because it will never go in the code.

I tried compacting it, separating the back and front end. but nothing works, same error. I'm on Windows Xp Sp3

Comment: Try holding down Shift when you open your project.  This should bypass running the code and take you into your development list of queries, tables, forms, etc.  See if you can start from there and set some breakpoints in your code.

Comment: I can go in the code, i can setup a break point, but since access work with event... well i can't fire up any code since any event has an Out Of Memory error. Maybe my form is corrupted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange errors like this are sometimes caused by a corrupt form in your database.  I would recommend trying to `decompile` the database file.

You can get more information about the `/decompile` switch from the following:

[How to Decompile a Database](http://datagnostics.com/dtips/decompile.html)

[Decompile Your Microsoft Access Database](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp)

I would make a backup copy of the database, then do a decompile, and then a compact.  Then open up the database and open your VBA Editor and Compile your code.  Then test it.

The `/decompile` switch has fixed many strange problems with Microsoft Access databases for me in the past.